# Using Javascript to filter and hide specific table rows

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create a filter feature that removes certain scores from a table based on min and max value.

My HTML:

```
<table id="historyTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Game #</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Strikes</th>
        <th>Spares</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>299</td>
        <td>29 Feb 2016</td>
        <td>Hello World Bowling Alley</td>
        <td>202</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> ...same thing as above repeated a few times </tr>
</table>
```

I've got a button that takes the user's input min and max values and passes it to the following JS function onclick:

```
function updateFilter(min, max) {
var table = document.getElementById('historyTable');   
var rowCount = table.rows.length-1; // since I don't want to include the header row

for(var i = 1; i<=rowCount; i++) {
    var scoreCheck = table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
    if(scoreCheck < min || scoreCheck > max) {
        $(table.rows[i].innerHTML).hide();
    }
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Also consider that hiding the rows via css may be a much easier solution.

Comment: `$(table.rows[i].innerHTML)` is wrong – when you pass HTML code (which is what .innerHTML returns) to $(), it will _create new HTML elements_ out of it. You want to hide the table row, so `$(table.rows[i]).hide()` (Although that is a rather crude mix of “vanilla” JavaScript and jQuery you have there … why not use jQuery “all the way”, if you are using it already?)

Comment: Thank you, that works! I'm pretty new to Javascript so I'm not entirely sure what I've done there. How would I go about doing it entirely in jQuery?

Comment: @CBroe – you should add that as an answer, not a comment. Claim your reputation! :)

Comment: jQuery is a crutch you should not use until you know you need.  You won't know you need until you first learn JavaScript.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out? Could you leave a comment?

Comment: I have looked at jQuery too, that also confused me - i tried for a few days before coming asking hopefully for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### [Example (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/vng3bspg/3/)

The fiddle includes some extra functions which were created to dynamically populate the table; however, this is the crux of the fiddle:

```
window.updateFilter = function(min, max) {
  var table  = document.getElementById('historyTable'),
      rows   = table.tBodies[0].rows,
      fields = { score: 3 };

  // loop over rows
  for (var i = 0, n = rows.length; i < n; i++) {
    // get the numerical score; notice the unary-plus (+) for integer conversion
    var scoreCheck = +rows[i].cells[fields.score].innerText;

    if (scoreCheck < min || scoreCheck > max) {
      hidden[i] = rows[i];               // cache hidden row
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';    // hide the entire row
    } 
    // if row has a good value, make sure its shown (unhide if hidden)
    else {
      // make sure another method didn't already unhide it
      if (hidden.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        hidden['' + i].style.display = ''; // set the styling so its visible
        delete hidden[i];                  // no longer need the value in cache
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

---

If anything, your code *`$(table.rows[i].innerHTML).hide()`* is attempting to hide a property, which probably results in an error.  You probably intended to hide the entire row:

```
$( table.rows[i] ).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the issues to correct:

1. Don't use `innerHTML` in this selector as it will create a new element, only in memory, and act on that:

   ```
   $(table.rows[i].innerHTML)
   ```

   Instead you should select the row element without `innerHTML`.
2. Without any code to show rows again, the effect of a second filter will not be as intended, because the previously hidden rows will not appear again if they fit the second filter. So you should better use `toggle` instead of `hide` and pass the boolean setting as argument.
3. When you read the cell content, don't use `innerHTML`, but the plain text content. Then also convert it to number so numerical comparisons work.
4. As you use jQuery, you could shorten your code quite a bit.

You could use this code:

```js
function updateFilter(min, max) {
    // As you use jQuery, use it to its ful potential:
    $('#historyTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
        // Don't retrieve HTML but text; convert to number with `+`
        var scoreCheck = +$(this).text();
        // Toggle instead of hide, so it works both ways:
        // Don't select providing HTML, but use a TR selector.
        $(this).closest('tr').toggle(min <= scoreCheck && scoreCheck <= max);
    });
}

$('#filter').click(function () {
    var min = +$('#min').val(); // invalid input will use 0 as minimum
    // Replace invalid max input with very high value, so everything will be shown
    var max = +$('#max').val() || 1e20;
    updateFilter(min, max);
});
```

```css
th, td { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;}
tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
table {font-size: 11px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="historyTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Game #</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Strikes</th>
        <th>Spares</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>299</td>
        <td>29 Feb 2016</td>
        <td>Hello World Bowling Alley</td>
        <td>202</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>298</td>
        <td>13 March 2016</td>
        <td>Kuwait Open</td>
        <td>158</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>297</td>
        <td>13 Oct 2015</td>
        <td>11th Columbia 300 Vienna Open</td>
        <td>213</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>296</td>
        <td>20 Mar 2016</td>
        <td>Brunswick Euro Challenge</td>
        <td>259</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
Min:<input id="min" size="6" value="180"> &nbsp; 
Max:<input id="max" size="6" value="210">
<button id="filter">Apply filter</button>
```